# 42703: no existe la columna Extent1.Discriminator

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-5

el problema es el siguiente, estoy intentando usar el sistema de roles de entityframework para un proyecto 4.7.2 (C#, MVC5) con postgresql y devuelve el siguiente error cuando quiero inicializar el proyecto:

42703: no existe la columna Extent1.Discriminator
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: Npgsql.PostgresException: 42703: no existe la columna Extent1.Discriminator

que salta cuando se ejecuta:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }
        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var dbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(dbContext);
            var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(roleStore);

            if (!manager.Roles.Any())
            {
                manager.Create(new ApplicationRole
                {
                    Name = "Admin"
                });
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }
```

y me ayude con esta pregunta a realizarlo, porque anteriormente, me fallaba cuando necesitaba pedir el rol del usuario (creado a mano desde la db)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459293/how-to-get-current-logged-in-users-roleid-in-mvc5

-edit:
este es mi ApplicationDbContext

```
namespace PFSoftware.CentroComercial.Models
{
    // Para agregar datos de perfil del usuario, agregue más propiedades a su clase ApplicationUser. Visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 para obtener más información.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Tenga en cuenta que el valor de authenticationType debe coincidir con el definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Agregar aquí notificaciones personalizadas de usuario
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: por el mensaje de error pareciera aun problema de mapping de la entidad, en el ApplicationDbContext estas mapeando alguna herencia ? porque por lo general un "Discriminator" se asocia a la herencia cuando mapeas varias clases que heredan de otra y requieren este campo para poder diferenciarse

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ahi agregue el applicationdbcontext, debido a que realmente, se que puede estar el error ahi, pero no logro saber donde esta el error, porque es la primera vez que me manejo con los roles de aspnet (siempre trabaje con uno propio)